# HTTP Client: What should it do when multiple A records for a domain?

Tags: python, sockets, http, tcp, dns

I’m writing an HTTP client, and wondering how it should behave when there are multiple A records for a domain.

For example, say a second concurrent connection request to a given domain is opened. Should it use another IP address? How about on connection error, should it try another IP automatically? Should
it “remember” an IP failed for later requests, and try others first?

Comment: Yes, yes, and maybe.

Comment: @KlausD. Feel free to add that as an answer! ;-)